# How to draw a simple table with colored cells in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, color

I am trying to draw a simple "array" data structure in Beamer using tabular. I would like to color some of the cells blue. Here is my M(N)WE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cellcolor{blue!25}A&
\cellcolor{blue!25}B&
\cellcolor{blue!25}C&
B&
A&
B&
C\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't compile.  How should it be done?

The first problem is

> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package
>   xcolor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "problem" is, that beamer automatically loads the `xcolor`-package. But luckily you can simply pass your desired option by using `\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cellcolor{blue!25}A&
\cellcolor{blue!25}B&
\cellcolor{blue!25}C&
B&
A&
B&
C\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|},
  hlines,vlines,
  cell{1}{1-3}={bg=blue!25}
}
A & B & C & B & A & B & C\\
\end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I now get only "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 18."

Comment: Is it just an illusion or are the letter positions high in their cells? They don't seem to be in the middle.

Comment: Concerning your font size problem: For me, this warning can be ignored, but if you want to get rid of it, have a look at http://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncategorized/beamer-warnings/ which basically suggest to include `\let\Tiny=\tiny` in the preamble

Comment: I am not sure it is an illusion in fact. I zoomed in a long way and there is clearly more space below than above the letters.

Comment: care to post a screenshot? or even open a new question?

Comment: The only thing that worked for me is: `\documentclass[table]{beamer}` without the xcolor

Comment: @Huhngut Is your beamer version up-to-date?

Comment: @Huhngut Do you maybe use the obsolete version 3.65? This one had a bug which caused problems with passing options to the xcolor package.

Comment: Yes. I do use the outdated version. I installed it via the apt package manager. Maybe someone has to update texlife-full

Comment: @Huhngut The texlive versions packages for linux are notoriously out of date. I would always install the vanilla version from tug.org The current beamer version is 3.70

Comment: Thats disapointing. Who controls them why arent they updated?

Comment: @Huhngut use the vanilla version, this way you can control yourself when you update texlive. Package updates are usually available in vanilla texlive within a day.